# Doubt in the pertubation theory for BVP

Tags: mathematical-modeling, perturbation-theory

I'm using the pertubation method to solve an ODE. And I just need a small clarification.
When I'm solving for the boundary Layer solution I got the following equation:
$$(Y^{''}_0+\epsilon Y_1^{''}+...)+\epsilon \bar{x}(Y^{'}_0+\epsilon Y_1^{'}+...)-(Y^{}_0+\epsilon Y_1^{}+...)=-e^{\bar{x}\epsilon}$$
My question is, when comparing the coefficients of $\epsilon^0$ should it be

$Y^{''}_0-Y_0=-e^{\bar{x}\epsilon}\qquad$  or is it $\qquad Y^{''}_0-Y_0=0$

Appreciate your help

Comment: Expand $e^{\bar x\epsilon}$ in a series as $1+\bar x\epsilon+\ldots$, then it will be much more obvious. You can always do this when doing perturbation theory to simplify nonlinear terms.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes it worked